# WebView App: Only Open External Links In Mob Browser

Tags: android, android-webview

There are 2 condition first open all links within App and second is that open all links in mobile browser.

But I want to open web site internal links within App and external link in mobile browser.

For Example: 
My app is a WebView of https://www.123.com and I am using amazon affiliate links in my web site(https://www.123.com)

Now I want that all links starting with https://www.123.com open within App and all amazon affiliate (external) links starting https://www.amazon.com open in mobile browser.

Answer (score 1):

Just override `shouldOverideURLoading` in `WebViewClient`.
You will get the links clicked inside the webview, then process accordingly.

```
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Request URL is " + request.getUrl());
        if (request.getUrl().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("www.123.com/affiliated")) {
               //DO SOMETHING
        } else {
               //DO SOMETHING
        }
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
    }
});
webView.loadUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/");
```

Please mark the answer as accepted if it worked.Thanks.

Comment: It will not work. After my App opens and showing the view of my web site then I want when some link on myApp it wil open inside App but

Comment: Please ignore my last comment. It will not work. I want my App opens normal and after my App opens and show the view of my web site then I want clicking on specific URLs  will open in mobile browsers and all other URLs open within App. e.g: a specific URL is that contain word "out". So, all URLs containing "out" will open in mobile browser.

Comment: Your comment is not clear enough.
The flow of the application you want is as follows.
The app opens webview which loads a particular website eg www.123.com. What you want is the links clicked inside www.123.com are routed accordingly.
Please correct me If I am wrong. Is this what you want ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Generally, there are 2 options open web site links within App or open in mobile browser. But I want to open website links within App but Affiliate links open in mobile browser. Actually, affiliate companies does not give commission if their links open within a App.

Comment: @awais I have updated the answer please have a look.